# SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "." Position: 115 -- Ideas? Wrong use of NEW keyword?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

The code is as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER avc
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON tbl_project_task 
  FOR EACH row
  execute procedure date_end_for_task(NEW.ptr_ca, NEW.ptr_ci);
```

Comment: Arguments to triggers are literal constants. `NEW` is implicitly defined inside the function you don't need to pass it.

Comment: @clamp - Thank you.

Comment: @clamp yep, it worked for me too and I had the same problem OP had.